# Including declarations of dependencies in built package

Tags: typescript, webpack

**Situation:**

We have the following packages/projects:

- Base package, which exports a class `BaseElement` that extends `HTMLElement`.

```
export class BaseElement extends HTMLElement {
   ...some properties and methods
}
```

- Elements package, which has the base package as a dependency and exports some elements which all extend the `BaseElement` from the base package. Let's say we have an `InputElement` for our examples.

```
import { BaseElement } from 'base-package';
export class InputElement extends BaseElement {
    ...some properties and methods
}
export function intializeInput() {
    customElements.define('input-element', InputElement);
}
```

- Our main project, which has the elements package as a dependency and uses these elements in its layout.

js file:

```
import { initializeInput } from 'elements-package';
initializeInput();
```

html file:

```
<input-element id="input-element"></input-element>
```

**The problem:**

We want the base package to be included in the elements package, so we don't need to install it in our main project (or other projects that need the elements package). This seems to work fine, until we try to do the following:

```
const inputElement = document.getElementById('input-element') as InputElement;
```

InputElement is an HTMLElement, so this should work. Typescript gives us the following error:

> Conversion of type 'HTMLElement' to type 'InputElement' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

Things also break when we try to use properties from `HTMLElement`:

```
const element: InputElement;
...
element.addEventListener(...)
```

This gives the error

> Property 'addEventListener' does not exist on type 'InputElement'.

How can we include the declarations from the base package in the build of the elements package? This used to be a single package, which included both the base class and the extends, and used to work fine that way, so I know the code itself is not the issue here. What can we do to fix this without having to cast everything to unknown first?

Note: adding the base package as a `devDependency` fixes all these issues, but is not an acceptable solution. We included the base package in the elements package to prevent needing to include it in every project, so adding it as a `devDependency` kind of defeats the purpose.

**Things we tried:**

We tried adding a declaration for the `BaseElement` in our element package like so:

```
declare module 'base-package' {
    export class BaseElement extends HTMLElement {}
}
```

This sadly didn't fix anything.

All these packages generate declaration files in their output. The d.ts files for the elements in the elements package all start with

```
import { BaseElement } from 'base-package';
```

We would like the declaration of BaseElement to be part of the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I have come up with a solution, albeit not a very elegant one. In my webpack config I added the following to my plugins:

```
plugins: [
    ...,
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
                { from: 'node_modules/base-package/**/*.d.ts', to: '[path][name].ts' }
        ]
    })
]
```

This causes all d.ts files to be added to the node_modules of the built package, after which typescript can find them and resolves all types correctly again.

**Important note:**

When  publishing the package, you need to add the `bundleDependencies` property to your package.json like so:

```
{
    "name": "my-package",
    ...,
    "dependencies": {
        ...,
        "base-package": "latest",
        ...
    },
    "bundleDependencies": [
        "base-package"
    ]
}
```

Instead of an array of package names, you can also provide the boolean value `true` if you want to bundle all dependencies in this way. Skipping this may cause an error when using the package in another project:

> "base-package"  not accessible from "my-package"